# Android Timer Task Issue

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, timer, android-runonuithread

I need a timer when Loaded ListView . Like " Waiting [(Timer) 42] Seconds for buy elements " I want to show users Textview Like it. I can't use Thread in ListView...

I get Error from runOnUiThread. Why ? I cant use timer In Listview.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final TextView LblTime;

        inflater=(LayoutInflater)Context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.test,parent,false);

        LblTime=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.LblFragmentAnaListViewKalanSure );

       Timer T=new Timer();
        T.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Context.getApplicationContext().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        long Time= MyTime.get(position).getTime() - (new Date()).getTime();
                        long Sec= Time/ 1000 % 60;
                        long Min= Time/ (60 * 1000) % 60;
   LblTime.setText(Min+":"+Sec);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.. for call atfer 42 sec..

```
(new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        // do you want
     }
 }, 42000);
```

if every sec you need to than do it..

> **This is using the Handler**

Initialize..

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

Import

```
import android.os.Handler;
```

call this for..

```
 handler.postDelayed(yourtask,42*1000);



 private Runnable yourtask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

      // Run your code..
        handler.removeCallbacks(yourtask);
        handler.postDelayed(yourtask, 42*1000); // again start...

    }
};
```

> **This is Using Timer every one second....**

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer timer = new Timer();
private int DELAY = 1000 * 60 * 1;
```

call this

```
   timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(doAsynchronousTask, 0, DELAY);
```

in class

```
  TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
             // your code


                }

            });


        }
    };
```

Comment: Every 42 sec ? or Just one ?

Comment: No no I need Loop it. I want to Loop every 42 sec . How can i do this ? Like I want to post something every 42or 20sec ... how can i loop it ?

Comment: Ohh okay.. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) it works perfectly in UI thread. All you need is just to initiate it in your code like that:

```
timer = new CountDownTimer(MS_TILL_COMPLETE, TICK_OFFSET) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            //Repeating every TICK_OFFSET
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            //Called after MS_TILL_COMPLETE
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: I am going to try it Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of timer try to use CountDownTimer

```
new CountDownTimer(10000, 20000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

        public void onFinish() {
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: I am going to try it Thank you